# Can a loss of power cause a dry fire condition, or vice versa?

Tags: water-heater

I had a Rheem Prestige Hybrid Electric Water Heater installed on in my pacific northwest home last November.
In January, one day our breaker tripped twice, for no apparent reason (no abnormal or heavy power consumption).

Today(mid March) the breaker tripped once, and then again an hour later. The second time, the unit displayed a "dry fire condition" alarm.  After resetting the alarm, it triggered again.  About 29 mins later, the breaker tripped again.

The last two days there has been some city water work on our block - not exactly sure what they are doing, but digging into the ground is about all I can see(I hadi really been paying much attention).

I'm sure the error message and the breaker are related, but not sure which is the cause, or if there is some other external cause, such as water work on the block?

I'll call for service in the morning butaybe someone can offer insight as to what might be the cause.

Comment: Has there been any interruption to your water supply?

Comment: A "dry fire condition" means the heater's heating element, usually surrounded and cooled by water, is instead...dry. Such a heating element gets too hot and can fracture; the fracture can ignite a fire. What you're experiencing could be triggered, as ThreePhaseEel asks about, by a water supply interruption.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, DavidSupportsMonica, there has been work happening on our block the last few days - I don't know exactly what they are doing. About a week ago they actually turned out water off for about 6 hours during the day.  Not sure if an event from a week ago could bubble up now, or if what they have been doing this week could have caused enough of an interruption(we haven't been without water during this time).  But if this were the cause, could this also be the underlying cause for it tripping the breaker?

Comment: Are your breakers GFCI? Have a test button? I agree with David’s explanation of dry fire but low voltage on a resistive heating element would draw less current and not affect a standard inverse time circuit breaker used in residential panels. Electrical work could be a possibility.

Comment: One thought that just occurred to me is that perhaps after the breaker trips and there is no power to the water heater - if we're unaware that it's off, would running the "hot" water drain the tank- would no power to the water heater prevent the tank from refilling?  Not sure how that works, but might explain that part.

Comment: UPDATE:  I talked to tech support for this particular water heater, and the rep assured me that the code that it's displaying (A008 Detected Dry Fire Condition) is the direct result of losing power.  It makes no sense why a power loss would cause that particular message to display, but she sounded like she knew that answer well and was very confident.  So that describes what's actually happening in terms of the water heater, at least.  This seems like an electrical issue and I'll be getting an electrician to help us figure out why the breaker keeps tripping.